# Add Button Title using swift in xcode

Tags: swift, xcode, button, uikit

How could I change the button title in swift?

I've tried the below code but it's not working:

```
button.setTitle("myTitle", for: .Normal)
```

Comment: Full code of `button.setTitle("myTitle", for: .Normal)`? Is `button` an `IBOutlet`? Is it an instance variable? Where is that button? When is called your code?

Comment: it's an IBOutlet button and I'm trying to set a title because I want to compare between two buttons to present an action

Comment: Check your attribute connection. You may be removed the connection.

Comment: is any of the answer helps you?

Answer (score 0):

```
@IBOutlet weak var defaultButton: UIButton! 
override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        defaultButton.setTitle("hello", for: .normal)
    }
```

// I Set button title in didload and further changed on button action
//button is so called as defaultButton

```
  @IBAction func addButtonTapped(_ sender: Any) {
        defaultButton.setTitle("myTitle", for: UIControl.State.normal) 
//defaultButton.setTitle("myTitle", for: .normal)
    }
```

The both methods are working fine !!

Answer (score 0):

if your button is an @IBOutlet and have proper attribute connection then the following line will work

```
button.setTitle("myTitle", for: .normal)
```